# Using PowerShell to Find All Expired Claims Provider certificates in an ADFS Instance

Tags: powershell, adfs

I ran into a snag when trying to build this out. Right now, I get the results I need with the below script I've been working on, but I'm getting multiple returns on a given Claims Provider Trust, (i.e multiple signing certificates for a given trust) which is throwing off my spreadsheets.

I'm looking to add a line (probably a Foreach statement of sorts) that picks the greater of two or more dates on a given return.

I tried adding a:

```
ForEach-Object { $CPDetails.TokenSigningCertificates.NotAfter| Sort-Object -Property NotAfter|Select-Object -Last 1}
```

to my if statement, but it causes the output to repeat the same value over and over.

```
$Results = @()

Try
{
    $CPDetails = (Get-AdfsClaimsProviderTrust | select  Name, TokenSigningCertificates)
}
Catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message
    Continue
}

If($CPDetails.TokenSigningCertificates)    
{
    $Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 
        NotAfter = $CPDetails.TokenSigningCertificates.NotAfter | ForEach-Object { $CPDetails.TokenSigningCertificates.NotAfter| Sort-Object -Property NotAfter|Select-Object -Last 1}
        Name = $CPDetails.Name
    }
}

$Results += $Object 

If($Results)
{ 
    $Results | Select-Object NotAfter, Name  | Sort-Object NotAfter | Out-GridView -Title "Certificates"
}
```

Currently:

```
DateTime { 12/31/2999 12:00:00 PM, 12/31/2999 12:00:00 PM, 12/31/2999 12:00:00 PM,

Name {Trust 1, Trust 2, Trust 3.....
```

Needs to be:

```
DateTime { 12/31/2999 12:00:00 PM, 01/2/2019 12:00:00 PM, 05/31/2021 12:00:00 PM,

Name {Trust 1, Trust 2, Trust 3.....
```

Comment: I think you need some sort of `$CDPDetails | Group Name | ForEach{$_.Group|Sort {$_.TokenSigningCertificates.NotAfter} | Select -First 1}` in there, so it gets the latest cert for each provider. Play around with that, and see if that gets you what you need.

Comment: Thanks; will try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up thinking of a more elegant solution than this mess I started with:

```
Get-AdfsClaimsProviderTrust |
Select name, @{Name='TokenSigningCertificates'; Expression={[string]::join(";", ($_.TokenSigningCertificates.NotAfter|
Group-Object Name |
Foreach-Object {$_.Group | Sort-Object * | Select-Object -Last 1}))}}
```

Thanks for the direction @TheMadTechnician